# C# Class Of Type Class -example linked list

Tags: c#

In Linked List There is a Public Node Next;
With class Node
But I didn't understand what does it mean???
I Understood that it leads To the next one
But didn't understand how class Node Of Next with no parameters or {}
Thank You

Comment: Please provide a question, maybe adding some code to explain your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Public Node Next;


Class Name Is Node
So Class Node, with word next

Comment: public class Node
        {
            public object data;
            public Node next;

            public Node(object value)
            {
                data = value;
                next = null;
            }

        }

Comment: this is my code but didn't understand public node next

Comment: how it is node of node class

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the class `Node` is called *recursion*.
Sometimes, recursion can be very useful in programming. For example, let's assume we're programming an internet message board, and we've got a class called `Message`. To find out a message's replies in the future, we create a property in it called `Replies`, which will be a `List<Message>`.
Full code example:

```
public class Message 
{
    public string Content { get; set; } // Text of the message
    public List<Message> Replies { get; set; } = new List<Message>(); // Its replies
    public Message(string text)
    {
        Content = text;
    }
    public void AddReply(Message m)
    {
         Replies.Add(m);
    }
}
```

So now, let's create an instance of the `Message` class, and add a few replies to it.

```
class Program 
{
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
          Message reply1 = new Message("Bar!");
          Message reply2 = new Message("Hello!");
          reply2.AddReply(new Message("Hello there!");
          Message msg = new Message("Foo!");
          msg.AddReply(reply1);
          msg.AddReply(reply2);
     } 
}
```

Explanation of what we just did:

We created a message with the text "Foo!" and added a few replies to it, one of which has a reply to itself.

Here's a graphical representation:
[C# Recursion example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0we3k.png)